# cakephp query selector not returning the specified fields

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with my query selector. my query looks like

```
   $products = $this->Categories->find()
                        ->where(['active' => 1])
                        ->contain(['Products' => function($q) {
                                return $q;
                            }
                        ]);
```

it return the list of categories, and a nested array of products for each category. In this case it is returing all the fields from products table.

but as soon as I change the `contain` like this

```
->contain(['Products' => function($q) {
                                    return $q->select(['code', 'name']);
                                }
                            ]);
```

then the products array are empty. Is there some thing which I am missing?

Comment: What type of association is `Products`? Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (`3.x.x`, see `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Version is `3.2.12` and `Products->belongsTo('Categories');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to include `category_id` in the list of selected fields

```
return $q->select(['code', 'name', 'category_id']);
```

otherwise cake doesn't know how to link the product to its category.

Usually you should see a warning about that but maybe you have debug mode turned off